# php работа с csv файлами, требуется вывести все товары с правильным наименованием категорий

Tags: php

доброе время суток.
входные данные

group.csv:

```
id;наименование;
1;Группа 1;
2;Группа 2;
3;Группа 3;
4;Группа 4;
```

products.csv:

```
id;категория;наименование;цена;
1;1;Товар1;10
2;2;Товар2;20
3;3;Товар3;30
4;4;Товар4;40
```

я их подключил пробежался по циклу

```
<?php 
$file1 = fopen("groups.csv", "r");
$file2= fopen("products.csv", "r");
$files = array($file1,$file2);

    foreach($files as $file){
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
    list($index,$value)= explode(';',trim($line));
    echo $line;
    echo '<hr><br>';
    }
}
?>
```

не могу понять, как мне сделать так, что бы к группе подставлял продукт и цену.

Comment: что из этого можно понять? https://ibb.co/12YW2y0

Comment: подправил информацию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вам требуется вывести все товары с правильным наименованием категорий.
Если так, то:

```
<?php
//Для начала формируем массив категорий.
$fileGroups = fopen("groups.csv", "r");
$groups = [];
while (($line = fgets($fileGroups)) !== false) {
    $data = explode(';', trim($line));
    if (!(int)$data[0]) continue;  //Это условие помогает пропустить заголовок из файла
    $groups[$data[0]] = $data[1];
}
fclose($fileGroups);
//Тепрерь в $groups у нас есть все категории из файла

//Заголовки из файлов мы игнорим и выводим свой собственный.
echo 'id;Категория;Продукт;Цена товара;';
echo '<hr><br>';
//Начинаем получать товары из файла и выводить их
$fileProducts = fopen("products.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgets($fileProducts)) !== false) {
    $data = explode(';', trim($line));
    if (!(int)$data[0]) continue; //Это условие помогает пропустить заголовок из файла
    //Формируем нужный для вывода массив данных
    $print = [
        $data[0],
        isset($groups[$data[1]]) ? $groups[$data[1]] : 'Неизвестная категория', //Подставляем категорию если она есть.
        $data[2],
        $data[3],
    ];
    // Выводим в нужном нам формате
    echo implode(';', $print);
    echo '<hr><br>';
}
fclose($fileProducts);
```

Соотвественно вывод я оставил такой же как был у вас. Для формирования красивой таблицы можете воспользоваться ответом от Bloom

Comment: вот что мне нужно:
Скрипт, получая на входе 2 файла с описанием иерархии групп товаров и самих товаров и их привязок к группам, должен вывести совместную иерархию групп и товаров.
Дочерние группы связаны с родительскими по полям “родитель”-”id”.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$file1 = fopen("groups.csv", "r");
$file2= fopen("products.csv", "r");
$files = array($file1,$file2);

    foreach($files as $file){
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
    $value[]= explode(';',trim($line));
  }

}

for($i = 0; $i <count($value); $i++) {
 echo'<table  cellspacing="0" border="2" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 200px">';
  echo'<tr>';

  echo '<td style="width: 200px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap">'.$value[$i][0].'<td style="width: 200px;">'.iconv('CP1251','UTF-8',$value[$i][1]).'<td style="width: 100px;">'.iconv('CP1251','UTF-8',$value[$i][2]).'<td style="width: 200px;">'.iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', $value[$i][3]).'<td style="width: 200px;">'.iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', $value[$i][4]).'</td>';

echo'</tr>';
echo'</table>';
}

?>
```

Comment: http://site-on.net/create/php/10-html-table-php